# How do I install a GUI from the command line?

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6

I have a CENTOS 6.0 machine that I have installed from a x86_64 minimal ISO. It runs at init 3 at the moment, and I want to install a GUI on it. When I do an init 5 from the prompt, all I get is "Starting system logger: 
Retrigger failed udev events [  OK  ]" and it does not boot a GUI.

What do I need to yum install to get a graphical user interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need X Windows at a minimum, and a desktop environment like Gnome or KDE (I am guessing you want a DE).

Use

```
yum grouplist
```

to find out what groups are available.  If you wanted KDE for example, you would need to install the following groups:

```
yum groupinstall "X Window System" "KDE (K Desktop Environment)"
```